# Ошибка с setrecurtionlimit() Python

Tags: python, рекурсия

Всем привет! Попробовал написать рекурсивную функцию для расчета факториала.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(60)
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*factorial(n-1)
```

Не могу понять, как работает `sys.setrecursionlimit()`. При вызове функции
`factorial(30)` выдает ошибку `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Почему так, если предел рекурсии был задан 60, а вызвал функцию с глубиной рекурсии 30?

А если поменять в функции `sys.setrecursionlimit(200)`, и вызвать функцию `factorial(195)`, то выдаёт другую ошибку: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, отчего так и как правильно ограничить глубину рекурсии? Спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7081448

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [У меня одного криво работает рекурсия на python3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1164918/%d0%a3-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python3)