# У меня одного криво работает рекурсия на python3?

Tags: python, рекурсия, python-3.6

Есть очень простой код, который запускает рекурсию и выводит текущую глубину рекурсии:

```py
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000000)


def rec(deep):
    print('deep =', deep)
    rec(deep + 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rec(0)
```

У меня он почему-то падает после глубины 3219, хотя в начале программы я установил огромный лимит рекурсии. Ошибка:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

Это у меня одного так?

Я запускал на Python3.6

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1148309/398802

Comment: @dIm0n На сколько я понял там речь о том, что один вызов рекурсии равняется примерно 5 операциям на стеке. Но даже так лимита 10^9 при глубине рекурсии около 3000 должно же хватать? Или Питон при каждом вызове рекурсии делает где-то миллион операций на стеке?

Comment: Лимит нужно задавать не только в питоне, но и в операционной системе

Answer (score 1):

Существует такое понятие как переполнение стека, оно не даёт вызывать рекурсию много раз. Для понимания нужно углубляться в особенности языка и операционных систем. Но лучше рекурсию заменить на цикл, это будет правильным решением

Comment: Все равно глубины рекурсии 10^9 должно хватать, разве нет? В моем случае конечно несложно переписать на циклы, но существуют задачи когда написать рекурсию раз в 100 проще и короче чем циклы. В других языках программирования рекурсия может заходить значительно глубже

Comment: @rew размер стека определяется не настройкой sys.setrecursionlimit, а настройками операционной системы, моя система позволяет вызвать мне рекурсию чуть больше чем 16.000 раз

Comment: @rew не сталкивался ни с 1 случаем рекурсии в реальных задачах, она если и вызывается то пару раз. Не понимаю смысла вызывать одну и ту же функцию миллионы раз, это какой-то бред. Если уж совсем никак по-другому используй цикл, это в тысячи раз ускорит твою программу

Comment: Очень жаль что python не оптимизирует хвостовую рекурсию. Если не прав, дайте знать)

Comment: @falm вы ребят немного не тот язык выбрали, у python другие задачи, хотите скорость, оптимизацию и производительность пишите на C =)

Comment: @Inventor, Я вот как раз по опыту на скале) эхх, удобная же штука

Comment: @falm не знаю кто сейчас пишет на этом языке, краем уха только слышал про него :D

Comment: @Inventor, Кто то пишет, точно тебе говорю =D

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111707/discussion-between-inventor-and-falm).

Answer (score 0):

Очень жаль что python не оптимизирует хвостовую рекурсию (из коробки).

Нашел статью:
https://towardsdatascience.com/python-stack-frames-and-tail-call-optimization-4d0ea55b0542

Там описывается решение с декоратором и с изменением байт-кода.

Сам не проверял.

Comment: https://github.com/reza-bagheri/tail-rec